# GLUT fetching the X11 Display*

Tags: x11, glut

I want to use XGrabKeyboard in my GLUT app. It wants `Display*` as a first argument. How do I fetch it from GLUT?

Comment: XOpenDisplay, but generally you should have it somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Okay, nevermind. I found up `glXGetCurrentDisplay()`